# WkWebView problems in macOS Mojave

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, wkwebview, appstore-sandbox

I have a very simple App that just displays a Website in a `WKWebView` but after upgrading to macOS Mojave i get some weird warnings messages.
The App compiles but doesn't start.

My Code:

```
@IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!

override func loadView() {
    webView = WKWebView()
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    view = webView
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
}
```

The warnings i get:

```
2018-10-08 19:27:24.466406+0200 MyApp[616:13277] [default] Unable to 
load Info.plist exceptions (eGPUOverrides)
2018-10-08 19:27:24.689229+0200 MyApp[616:13232] [User Defaults] 
Couldn't read values in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x600002910070> (Domain: 
com.apple.Accessibility, User: kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: No, 
Container: kCFPreferencesNoContainer, Contents Need Refresh: No): 
accessing preferences outside an application's container requires user- 
preference-read or file-read-data sandbox access
```

Since macOS Mojave isn't that old I didn't find anything useful on the internet. I hope someone can help me.

EDIT: The second warning can be stopped by turning off "App Sandbox" in Project -> Capabilities

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by enabled Sandbox being enabled.  Disabled that in Capabilities -> Sandbox.

```
accessing preferences outside an application's container requires user- preference-read or file-read-data sandbox access
```