# Xcode Cocoa: Couldn't read values in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x600002909f10>

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode10, swift4.2

I'm trying to implement WKWebView on Cocoa/MacOS but I'm getting this error:

> Unable to load Info.plist exceptions (eGPUOverrides)
>   Couldn't read values in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x600002909f10>
>   (Domain: com.apple.Accessibility, User: kCFPreferencesCurrentUser,
>        ByHost: No, Container: kCFPreferencesNoContainer, Contents Need Refresh: Yes): accessing preferences outside an application's container requires user-preference-read or file-read-data sandbox access

Here is my implementation:

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let url = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com") {
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            webView.load(request)
        }
    }
}
```

My question is how can I fix this issue on my implementation?

Comment: The error is stating that your app is not entitled to access (com.apple.Accessibility); have you added the entitlement?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52707411/wkwebview-problems-in-macos-mojave

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to read values in CFPrefsPlistSource iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275395/failed-to-read-values-in-cfprefsplistsource-ios-10)